# Spring, Hibernate annotation configuration - Dynamic

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

I have following requirement, where my application should be functioning either with H2 or Mysql database, based on a configuration in the application.properties file.

As a result, I should be able to attach dynamically the correct Hibernate Sequence generator or Identity generator for the primary key.

For instance,

If I am using MySQL database,

Then entity id field should have following

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "IdOrGenerated")
@GenericGenerator(name = "IdOrGenerated", strategy = "com.abc.emenu.api.model.MySQLIdentityGenerator")
private Long flagId;
```

if H2,

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "IdOrGenerated")
@GenericGenerator(name = "IdOrGenerated", strategy = "com.abc.emenu.api.model.H2SequenceGenerator")
private Long flagId;
```

is there a way to make this decision dynamically

Thanks in advance for any insight into the resolving this.

Comment: you can set the H2 DB to a [mysql mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes). Maybe you can use `MySQLIdentityGenerator` for both of the databases.